# Deploying Rails App on Elastic Beanstalk - Is WEBrick automatically replaced by passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, webrick

Quick Question:

I develop a ruby on rails application on my laptop.  Rails has WEBrick installed as an out of the box APPLICATION server.

I deploy my app on amazon web services elastic beanstalk.

I choose The configuration: Ruby 2.2 with Passenger version 2.0.8, which contains:

64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.8 running Ruby 2.2 (Passenger Standalone)

Ruby 2.2.3

RubyGems 2.4.5.1

Passenger 4.0.59 - Application server

nginx 1.8.0 - Web server.

When I deploy my app, does elastic beanstalk automatically replace WEBrick with passenger??? Or-- do I need to install the passenger gem myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  I used the AWS GUI console online to download the virtual server's instance logs.  I checked the ed-activity.log file and saw that the server was started with passenger.

So, yes, Amazon Elastic Beanstalk automatically runs passenger even without the passenger gem in the gemfile.

Side note, when I tried to deploy the rails app with the passenger gem, I ran into a lot of problems.  AWS EB runs passenger standalone 4.0.59 while HomeBrew installs passenger 5.0~something or other...  This conflict will take down your entire server instance.

Comment: You might also want to include `gem "passenger"` in your Gemfile so that you're also using Passenger in your local environment.